# Type 'string | result[]' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<result> | null | undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular, key-value, ngfor

I am trying to display a document (object) retreived from a Firebase DB on my web app. The object I am working with has the following interface/type

```
export interface seasonResultsObject {
  sport: string;
  country: string;
  league: string;
  season: string;
  results: result[];
}
```

I only want to display the results array - which is an array of objects themselves. I dont want to display all the other key value pairs. In that light I have built the following template:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-workspace-nav></app-workspace-nav>
  <div *ngFor="let key of seasonDocument | keyvalue">
    <div *ngIf="key.key === 'results'">
      <!-- {{key.value}} -->                       
      <div *ngFor="let result of key.value">
        {{ result }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The logic is as follows: Go through all the key value pairs in the documents, if you find the result key, then display (only) that key value pair's value - that line is now commented out, but it works perfect and displays a list of objects on the page as follows:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

The problem is this piece of code:

```
      <div *ngFor="let result of key.value">
        {{ result }}
      </div>
```

Logically is should interate through `key.value` which is an array/list of object of type `result`, but I am getting the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string | result[]' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<result> | null | undefined'.

6       <div *ngFor="let result of key.value">
```

For referance the result object looks as follows:

```
export interface result {
  [key: string]: any;
  Div: string;
  Date: number;
}
```

I would love some ideas on what I am doing wrong and how I could fix it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the data is the Array in your returned model why can't you just iterate over that?

Comment: You're looping through `seasonResultsObject` so I guess one of its `results` key is not pointing to an array

Comment: @DarrenStreet Good point - that is what I have now done

Comment: @AmadouBeye the *ngIf statement resolves that issue...

Comment: @RubenFerreira the *ngIf only check if the name of the key is `results`...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-workspace-nav></app-workspace-nav>
  <div *ngFor="let key of seasonDocument | keyvalue">
    <div *ngIf="key.key === 'results'">
      <div style="text-align: center;" *ngFor="let result of seasonDocument.results">
        <div style='display: flex'>
          <div style='padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 1rem;'>{{ result.Date }}</div>
          <div style='padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 1rem;'>{{result.HomeTeam}}</div>
          <div style='padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 1rem;'>{{result.FTHG}}-{{result.FTAG}}</div>
          <div style='padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 1rem;'>{{result.AwayTeam}}</div>
        </div>
       
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But still have no idea why I had the error on the orginal question - logically it should have worked... perhaps someone can still give me guidance on that.

Comment: Are you sure it is `result of seasonDocument.results` ?